# Counter to add up number of issues/failures for a summary at the end

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gnu

I have a makefile like this:

```
default:
%:
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir1 $*
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir2 $*
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir3 $*
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir4 $*
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir5 $*
```

The basic concept is that I have 5 (or more) sub projects which I will call make on sequentially. I use "-i" flag so that the make can continue to the end and the "-C dir" flag to call make in a sub-directory.

So, lets say that sub project 2 and 5 are failing, then at the end I want to be able to print something like:

```
3 projects built ok, 2 projects have errors.
```

So I think I want a counter of some sort, but I have no idea how I can set/increment it on an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every call to `$(MAKE)` spawns its own subprocess, I can't think of a way to record these numbers easily with an ordinary make variable. You can, however, log the return value of each invocation to a (possibly hidden) file and then `grep` for your build stats like this:

```
errLog = .errLog

default:
%:
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir1 $*; echo $$? > $(errLog)
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir2 $*; echo $$? >> $(errLog)
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir3 $*; echo $$? >> $(errLog)
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir4 $*; echo $$? >> $(errLog)
    @$(MAKE) -i -C subdir5 $*; echo $$? >> $(errLog)
    @echo "`grep -c '^0' $(errLog)` built ok, `grep -c '^[^0]' $(errLog)` have errors."
```

Note that the first output redirection must be a single `>` to overwrite previous return codes in the file, while all others should be two `>` to not overwrite the file content.

Comment: That's really nice actually. Could even probably delete the .errlog file at the end to be "super tidy" ` && rm $(errLog)` at the end of the last line :).   But what is really cool - is that somehow using `; echo $$? ....` at the end of each line seems to negate the need for the "-i" flag! I guess because we are consuming the $? and echo always returns true. So ... all around a really nice solution thanks very much : )